# Wired keyboard for iPad Mini

Tags: ipad, keyboard, case

Is there any **wired** keyboard-case available for new iPad Mini (thefore using *Lightning* port)? Or keyboard-case with standard USB cable, that has been tested and proven to work with [Lightning OTG Adapter](http://dx.com/p/usb-female-to-8-pin-lightning-male-otg-adapter187347)? Does anyone have any experience in this area to share?

I did a really good (as I think) research on this in the Internet, but all I've found is a really big bunch of wireless Bluetooth-based keyboard-cases for iPad Mini. Plus some entries that only suggest that a wired keyboard-case *should* work.

I don't like the entire idea of charging keyboard aside of charging iPad itself. So the best solution for me would be either keyboard-case with Lightning cable or keyboard-case with standard USB plug, proven to work with iPad Mini through OTG adapter.

Thank you in advance for any help here.

Comment: I have a wireless bluetooth keyboard (from Apple) that I use for my computer at home and my iPad. I use it ~ 5 hours a day and the battery lasts ~ 6 months or longer. So I won't worry about charging the keyboard aside of charging the iPad itself. Also you will get an notification when the battery is running low early enough so you would have some days to switch or charge batteries

Comment: +1 The Wireless Apple Keyboard has a really big battery life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it won't work. Apple disabled the functionality a while ago with an iOS update. It only worked for few months on the first iPad with the Camera connection kit.

I tested it on my iPad 2. If I remember well, when connecting an Apple USB keyboard it poped a message that said the connector can't provide enough power ... Probably a fake reason because it worked before.